# Call scp from VB.net running under Wine on Ubuntu

Tags: vb.net, ubuntu, scp, wine

There are a few question around this subject but nothing that answers my question (at least, nothing that I found).

I have a VB.Net app built on .Net 4.8 that I run under Wine (via CrossOver, in case that matters) on Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to add a feature to this app whereby it calls scp to transfer some files over to another Linux server.

I tried the obvious (assume there are valid parameters here)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("scp")
```

However, this just said there was no app associated.

Is there a way to call to Linux commands from VB.net running under Wine?

Comment: @AndrewMorton There is no Windows in this scenario. Well, the development is done on Windows but the app is running on Ubuntu and it will (hopefully) scp to a Linux server.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I misunderstood the scope of Wine. And it doesn't help with searching that there's a game named "SCP: Containment Breach" that people want to run under Wine.

Comment: Yeah, everyone likes short names, which leads to so much duplication (or ambiguity) out there. Makes searching a pain.

Comment: I wondererd if the [.NET assembly of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install) would work, but there is a second .exe involved.

Comment: I wonder if there might be a path issue where it just doesn't know where to look to find scp?